# Изменить картинку при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток.
Ситуация такая: на сайте есть видео, вставил его с помощью тега video, так сделал кнопку плэй и пауза, по умолчанию видео проигрывается сразу как только загрузилась страница, и картинка у кнопки стоит Пауза.
Я сделал что бы по клику на кнопку у видео срабатывает пауза, но мне нужно что бы еще и менялась картинка с Паузы на Плэй.

Я пробывал с jquery с добавлением класса у которого бэгроунд с нужной картинкой, но это срабатывает тольок один раз когда клинешь то класс подставляется, картинка меняется на плэй но по второму клику не чего не меняется, видео срабатывает пауза и картинка стоит Плэй хоть видео проигрывается хоть и на паузе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны при клике второй раз удалять этот класс, который вы добовляли:

```js
$(".play-pause").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("pause");
});
```

```css
.play-pause {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
  background-size: cover;
}

.pause {
  background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="play-pause"></div>
```